# Linkedlist in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to create a linkedlist in C with pointers to structs at the moment. I am having some issues with my logic. So I was wondering, when removing the head of the list, would I return the removed item, OR, would I return the new head of the list. Also if I would return the new head, how would I free the memory? (This part is for an assignment) According to the assignment information, we are not supposed to free the removed item in the function. So yea, my question is, where would I free the memory? Here is that snippet of code. My code here just returns the new head, or returns NULL if the list is empty.

```
MusicRec * removeFromFront(MusicRec * theList)
{
    if(theList == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    } 
    return theList->next;
}
```

Comment: Where else should the freeing take place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. Every allocation function has a companion deallocation function, and sometimes a whole suite of additional utility functions. Look in the docs for your allocator.

Deallocate just before you return. That might mean you need a temporary copy.

BTW: You are returning the proper value...

Comment: see, for this assignment my professor is not going to be marking in person, but is going to have a program to mark it for her. So I am supposed to use pre written header files, and I am afraid to add anything that isn't already there.

Answer (score 1):

```
MusicRec *removeFromFront(MusicRec  **theListref)
{
    if(*theListref == NULL)
        return NULL;    // shouldn't there be an underflow error?
    Musicref *oldhead = *theListref;
    *theListref = *theListref->next;
    return oldhead;
}
```

I'm returning the pointer to old head. This can be freed in the calling function. The parameter is a **reference** to the current head pointer.

**EDIT**
If I have to stick to your interface, your code is perfectly all right & I'll clean up memory in the calling function:

```
theListCopy = theList;
theList = removeFromFront(theList);
//free the ListCopy here
```

Comment: Depends very much on which interface is wanted... Well, OP should know.

Comment: We already have a pre written header file. This is exactly what I did on my previous linked list that I coded before.

Comment: You mean it should be `MusicRec *removeFromFront(MusicRec  *theList)`?

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what it should be.

Comment: Then your code is correct. Free memory in the calling function

Comment: nope. The function must return the corrected list, but cannot return the node which shall be deallocated. So he is right that he must do it.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's why I'm first making a copy of the current head. The function need not return the node which shall be deallocated since it's the current head anyway and we already have the reference to it. Also, it says in the question that he's not supposed to free the memory inside the function.

Comment: I'm sure the OP must implement a whole suite of list manipulation functions with a somewhat uniform interface. How will you do it for insert, replace and remove_at or such? Also, that would break encapsulation (doing the whole task, not only a part).

Comment: I KNOW that. It's not what I would do. But if it's in the specifications it's in the specifications.

Answer (score 1):

The function should save a pointer to the node being removed (the current head node), reset the head of the list to the next node (i.e. the current 2nd node) and then return the saved pointer to the removed node.

The user using your linked list api may have some complex structure being used as the node and in that case it is best left up to the caller to handle the memory cleanup of the data.

Comment: Well, the grader that my prof is using, checks for memory leaks, so I do need to free memory.

Comment: Well given that constraint then yes, definitely free the memory; in which case just return the new head of the list or nothing depending on your requirements.